# SQLite query for finding similar words using the SQLite "like" clause

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios4, sqlite

In my iPhone app, I have requirement to search the SQLite database.

I will search the similar data on the basis of what the user enters into the textbox.

**What I want:**

I want query like

**Select category from categorytable where category like 'A%'**, if user enters A

I tried

```
NSString *query = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Select category from categorytable where category like '%@%'",textbox1.text];
```

It does not show the "%" after the character entered by the user.

In console it shows like

```
**Select category from categorytable where category like 'A'**  which is incorrect
```

What should be the query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use %% in stringWithFormat.

Answer (score 2):

The string format specifiers document says that if you want the `%` literal character to appear in the final string, you should use `%%` in the format string.  So you should be using `'%@%%'`

Answer (score 0):

As others have said, use `%%` syntax in `stringWithFormat` to have the literal percent sign appear within the search string. But, do not do that with your SQL. Only do that with the value. One should avoid using `stringWithFormat` to insert text values directly into the SQL. Instead, using `?` placeholders in the SQL:

```
NSString *value = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%%", textbox1.text];

NSString *query = @"Select category from categorytable where category like ?";
```

Then prepare your `sqlite3_stmt` using `query` and then `sqlite3_bind_text` with the `value`. For example:

```
sqlite3_stmt *statement;
int rc;

if ((rc = sqlite3_prepare_v2(db, [query UTF8String], -1, &statement, NULL)) != SQLITE_OK) {
    NSLog(@"%s (%ld)", sqlite3_errmsg(db), (long)rc);
} else {
    if ((rc = sqlite3_bind_text(statement, 1, [value UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT)) != SQLITE_OK) {
        NSLog(@"%s (%ld)", sqlite3_errmsg(db), (long)rc);
    }
    while ((rc = sqlite3_step(statement)) == SQLITE_ROW) {
        const unsigned char *string = sqlite3_column_text(statement, 0);
        NSLog(@"%s", string);
    }
    if (rc != SQLITE_DONE) {
        NSLog(@"%s (%ld)", sqlite3_errmsg(db), (long)rc);
    }
    sqlite3_finalize(statement);
}
```

Or, if using FMDB:

```
FMResultSet *rs = [db executeQuery:query, value];
NSAssert(rs, @"%@", [db lastErrorMessage]);

while ([rs next]) {
    NSLog(@"%@", [rs resultDictionary]);
}
[rs close];
```

This is important, to prevent problems stemming from the occurrences of `'` characters within the value (e.g., if  you're looking for "Bob's Bar and Grill").